# How to set max height for text-angular component

Tags: angularjs, textangular

I need to set max-height for this this text editor.so I need a scrollable text editor if its height bigger than 200px.

The example is here. I am using like that also.

http://triangular.oxygenna.com/#/elements/textangular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the editor's css class-

```
 max-height : 200px;
 overflow-y : scroll;
```

Comment: Thanks.I have added inside textangular.css file and it has worked.